# Python discord bot development. Audio broadcast

Tags: python, audio, discord, bots

I am a beginner Python developer.
I'm developing a Discord bot, or rather two. Their task is to relay sound from channel 1 to channel 2. The problem is that I don’t really understand how to create this audio stream. Please tell me how to implement this.

I found an implementation of audio recording, but it's not an audio stream.

```py
@bot.command()
async def record(ctx):  # If you're using commands.Bot, this will also work.
    voice = ctx.author.voice

    if not voice:
        await ctx.respond("You aren't in a voice channel!")

    vc = await voice.channel.connect()  # Connect to the voice channel the author is in.
    connections.update({ctx.guild.id: vc})  # Updating the cache with the guild and channel.

    vc.start_recording(
        discord.sinks.WaveSink(),  # The sink type to use.
        once_done,  # What to do once done.
        ctx.channel  # The channel to disconnect from.
    )
    await ctx.respond("Started recording!")


async def once_done(sink: discord.sinks, channel: discord.TextChannel, *args):
    recorded_users = [
        f"<@{user_id}>"
        for user_id, audio in sink.audio_data.items()
    ]
    await sink.vc.disconnect()
    files = []

    for user_id, audio in sink.audio_data.items():
        file_name = f"{user_id}.{sink.encoding}"
        audio.file.seek(0)  
        i = 0
        with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
            file.write(audio.file.read())  
            convert_wav_to_mp3(file_name,f"{i}.mp3")
            i = i + 1
        discord_file = discord.File(file_name)
        files.append(discord_file)


@bot.command()
async def stop_recording(ctx):
    if ctx.guild.id in connections:  # Check if the guild is in the cache.
        vc = connections[ctx.guild.id]
        vc.stop_recording()  # Stop recording, and call the callback (once_done).
        del connections[ctx.guild.id]  # Remove the guild from the cache.
        await ctx.delete()  # And delete.
    else:
        await ctx.respond("I am currently not recording here.")  # Respond with this if we aren't recording.

def convert_wav_to_mp3(input_file, output_file):
    command = ['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, output_file]
    subprocess.run(command)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.